# CORS and Spring Websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, cors, stomp

I have followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to build a Spring Boot application that serves `websockets` connections but I can't connect to these websockets from other clients than the one served by Spring Boot itself.

The [`complete` directory in the GitHub repository that accompanies the tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/master/complete) contains the final Spring Boot code. I took the `index.html` and the `app.js` files from this repository and created another client that runs on a Node.js server. After that, I replaced the connection strings to point to `localhost:8080` (where Spring Boot is running). Then I ran the Node.js server and tried to use the websockets, but it does not work.

The first problem was easily solved by adding `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` to the `StompEndpointRegistry` registry. With this configuration, I managed to connect to the websocket, but now I never get a message back from the socket.

I wonder what am I missing... Does any one know what is the problem?

The extracted `index.html` and `app.js` (renamed to `index.js`) files, and [the Node.js server can be found here](https://github.com/brunokrebs/websocket-client) for testing purposes. To run it, simply install the dependencies (`npm install`) and then issue `npm start`. The server will respond on http://localhost:3000/.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the question/problem was quite stupid. The problem was that when I extracted the HTML/JS files to an external application, I changed all hardcoded three points in the code to `http://localhost:8080/...`:

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket');
// ...
stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080/topic/greetings', cb);
// ...
stompClient.send("http://localhost:8080/app/hello", ...);
```

The only line that I should have changed was the first one. The other two are just functions to `subscribe` and `send` message to topics on an already-open socket. Therefore, they don't need the URL as the prefix...

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket');
// ...
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', cb);
// ...
stompClient.send("/app/hello", ...);
```